# Opencv Mat For loop stops before it is supposed

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in C++ and have some difficulties using Opencv matrices.
I did a double For loop on a Mat CV_8UC1 to make a thresholding on my image but it stops at  i=0 and j=610/620 (not always the same value for j).
The image has a size of 1920x1080 pixels. 
inputframe and outputframe have the same type.
My code enter in the if(m_Tracker_On==false)  and don't go further because it stops inside.

```
void TorpedoTracker::hsv_thresholding(Mat& inputframe,Mat& outputframe)
{
    uint8_t black=0;
    uint8_t white=255;

    if (m_Tracker_On==false)
    {
        cout << "tracker off " << endl;
        for (int i=0; i<m_cols;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<m_rows;j++)
            {
                if ((inputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)<m_LowHSVThreshValue0) || (inputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)>m_HighHSVThreshValue0))
                {
                    outputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)=black;
                }
                else
                {
                    outputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)=white;
                }
            }
        }
        m_Tracker_On=true;

        cout << "now tracker on " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<m_ROISize*2;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<m_ROISize*2;j++)
            {
                if (inputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)<m_LowHSVThreshValue || inputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)>m_HighHSVThreshValue)
                {
                    outputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)=black;
                }
                else
                {
                    outputframe.at<uint8_t>(j,i)=white;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I first thought it was a type problem, like I was trying to access to a bigger variable type than 8 bits but I use only uint8 so I don't know...

Comment: Usually we much prefer questions including a [mcve]...

Comment: If it enters the loops and exits in the middle it is probably that m_cols or m_rows are set incorrectly, since it does not have a break. It should be (in my opinion) inputframe.cols and inputframe.rows... Also, take a look to the opencv function inrange and to [this OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)... it is more or less what you want to do

Comment: Usually, we use `i` to index in row and `j` to index in column. Also, if you have to write loops to iterate over a matrix, it is more efficient to iterate in row then in column.

Comment: Thank everyone for your advice. @api55 you are right. I was used to work with 1920x1080 images and then it changed and I forgot to change it in the code...